# Show a loading animation while function completes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a function inside my .aspx.cs code which takes wuite a long time to do the processing until when I want to display a cool loading animation. 
I looked some of the earlier posts but either these didn't work for me, or were having solution specific to Page loading scenario (not loading a while a function completes).

I guess the right approach would be to fire a Javascript startLoader() function just before the the main function starts (which takes a long time), and then call a stopLoader() from the .aspx.cs itself to stop the loader when the function ends. Any suggestions how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've done this in ASP.NET Web From (not a ASP.NET MVC solution). You need to provide OnSubmit client side event handler. It basically break down to three parts: Javascript, HTML Div, and one line code behind:

Javscript:

```
    function ShowLoading(e) {
        // var divBg = document.createElement('div');
        var divBg = document.getElementById('blockScreen');
        var divLoad = document.createElement('div');
        var img = document.createElement('img');

        img.src = 'images/ajax-loader.gif';
        divLoad.setAttribute("class", "blockScreenLoader");
        divLoad.appendChild(img);

        divBg.appendChild(divLoad);

        document.getElementById('blockScreen').style.display = 'block';

        // These 2 lines cancel form submission, so only use if needed.
        //window.event.cancelBubble= true;
        //e.stopPropagation();
    }

    function HideLoading() {
        //alert('hideloading');
        document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = null;
        document.getElementById('blockScreen').style.display = 'none';
        //alert('done');
    }
```

Add following DIV

```
 <div id="blockScreen" class="blockScreen" style="display:none">&nbsp;</div>
```

Finally, add the following to Page_Load in code behind.

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "submit", "ShowLoading()");
```

Now, all of your page postbacks are essentially have to call onsubmit event. It will display the animation before the page postback finishes.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to do, then the only way is webworkers. You've probably heard about them, or if not, i seriously recommend to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fire startLoader() on OnCliencClick of your button or whatever element you are using to fire the server-side event and call stopLoader() from the server-side at the end of your process. Something like this:

```
//rest of the server-side code above ...
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "someKey", "stopLoader();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that the browser is not responsive in the meantime, the simplest way of doing this is using an animated gif:

- [Activity indicators](http://mentalized.net/activity-indicators/)
- [ajaxload.info](http://www.ajaxload.info/#preview)
- [webscriptlab](http://www.webscriptlab.com/)

The trick is showing the image when starting your processing, and hiding it when finished. You can show it in an img, and use jQuery or whatever you want to show/hide it.

If you need the browser to keep responsive, use Web Workers. But be aware that some of the older browsers don't support it. [See this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers)